# При повторном нажатии текст не прячется(Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.view-source .hide').hide();
  $('.view-source a').on('click', function() {
    $('.view-source .hide').slideUp(300);
    $(this).parent().find('.hide').slideDown(300);
  });
});
```

```css
.view-source {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
  color: #75bde3;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 260px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.lesson__item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #75bde3;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border: solid 1px #5683a2;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="view-source">
    <a href="#">Урок 1</a>
    <div class="hide lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="hide lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="hide lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="hide lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-source">
    <a href="#">Урок 2</a>
    <div class="hide lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="hide lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="hide lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lessons .view-source').on('click', f_acc);
});

function f_acc() {
  $('#lessons .hide').not($(this).next()).slideUp(500);
  $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
}
```

```css
.view-source {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
  color: #75bde3;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 260px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.lesson__item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #75bde3;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border: solid 1px #5683a2;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lessons">
  <div class="view-source"><a href="#">Урок 1</a></div>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-source"><a href="#">Урок 2</a></div>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lessons .hide').hide();
  $('#lessons .view-source').on('click', function() {
    $('#lessons .hide').not($(this).next()).slideUp(300);
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
.view-source {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
  color: #75bde3;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 260px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.lesson__item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #75bde3;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border: solid 1px #5683a2;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lessons">
  <div class="view-source"><a href="#">Урок 1</a></div>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-source"><a href="#">Урок 2</a></div>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
    <div class="lesson__item">Спрятанный текст</div>
  </div>
</div>
```